# How to remove rows based on different column values in R?

Tags: r

I have a 24h temporal series (it's a really big data) which I have to work only in certain periods of time. Like in hour = 7, 15 and 23.

I have to remove all the other rows that correspond to the 1, 2, 3, 4... hours. I have to filter the rows in a gap of 40 hours. I will have to always stay with the ones that correspond to the 7, 15 and 23h of a day.

I've been struggling to create another data.frame including only these rows and even just NULL the worthless ones.

I added one print from my data. The columns represent the months, days & hours of 1955. It keeps going until the last day and hour record of 1955.

Data Example

[image: Data Example.]

Comment: Try including some example data so that others can better understand your question.

Comment: It depends on the format of the time series. For example, with POSIXlt, there is an hour attribute, so you could do `subset(DF, mycol$hour %in% c(7, 15, 23))`. Without example data, it is hard to pin down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to select the 7th, 15th, and 23rd hours based on the data in the screen capture, using the base R extract operator, is as follows.

```
Tempo <- c(0,3600,7200,10800,1440,18000,21600,25200,28800,
           23400,36000,39600,43200,46800,50400,5400,57600,
           61200,64800,68400,72000,75600,79200,82800)
Ano <- rep(1955,24)
Mes <- rep(1,24)
Dia <- rep(1,24)
Hora <- 0:23
NiveldoMar <- c(1.07,0.91,0.81,0.78,0.91,1.05,1.32,1.57,
               1.60,1.48,1.30,1.07,1.10,1.22,1.42,1.45,1.40,1.32,
               1.27,1.40,1.62,NA,NA,NA)
ContoleInterno <- rep(0,24)

data <- data.frame(Tempo,Ano,Mes,Dia,Hora,NiveldoMar)
# select data from hours 7,15, and 23
data[data$Hora %in% c(7,15,23),]
```

...and the output:

```
> data[data$Hora %in% c(7,15,23),]
   Tempo  Ano Mes Dia Hora NiveldoMar
8  25200 1955   1   1    7       1.57
16  5400 1955   1   1   15       1.45
24 82800 1955   1   1   23         NA
>
```